# convert sign like trademark to alphanumeric string

Tags: php, magento, unicode-string

during magento upgrade some of product urls had been changed to what was inside product names, for example, I tried to detect the ones that had trademarks that magento converted them to usual url keys,

for example the product name was:

```
strikeline™-rugged-led
```

and URL became as:

```
strikelinetm-rugged-led
```

is there any function to convert the trademark and other unicode signs to the alphabetic letters? I need it to detect some portion of changed urls.I don't know much about UTF8 but by using

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I was able to see trade marks in good format, now I need to convert the ™ to tm , I also have other signs, this is just for clarification.

Comment: I'm guessing the name was actually `strikeline<sup>tm</sup>`, and not `strikeline&trade;`? How do you plan to tell legitimate words that happen to have `tm` in them apart from actual trademarks?

Comment: That is one other challenge that you just brought up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code awhile back (http://cubiq.org/the-perfect-php-clean-url-generator)

```
<?php

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
function toAscii($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
    if( !empty($replace) ) {
        $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
    }

    $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
    $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);

    return $clean;
}

echo toAscii('strikeline™ rugged led');


?>
```